# NSTable/OutlineView: Edit textfield in a row without selecting the row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield, nsoutlineview

#### Context:

I have an NSOutlineView that acts like a source list, but does not use the actual source list highlighting style. (Imagine the sidebar in the Finder.)

This outlineView has only two levels: 1) "groups" and 2) "subitems". There is no additional nesting --- again, just like the source list in the Finder.

#### What I Want:

The top-level "group" rows in my OutlineView are `NSTableCellViews` with a single `NSTextField`. I would like my users to be able to edit the text in this textField (to rename the group) **WITHOUT** allowing them to select the entire group row in the OutlineView.

So far, I've not found a way to do this. If I prevent selection of group rows in my delegate for the OutlineView, it is not possible to edit the textfield. When I *allow* selection of the group rows, then I can get the textfield to edit just like any other.

Short of subclassing things and handling mouse events myself, is there a simple way to do this? Must a row in an NSTableView always be selected before textFields in that row can be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work to use a custom subclass of `NSOutlineView` in which you override `-validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent:` to return true if the proposed first responder is in a group row. Return whatever super returns for any other proposed first responder.

You can determine which row the proposed first responder is in by calling `-rowForView:`.

See this [blog post](http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2014/04/nstableview-tips-not-delaying-the-first-responder/) from the Apple engineer who wrote the view-based table view stuff.

Comment: This works perfectly. However, I'm going to have to re-think my approach. I see why Apple required row selection before editing a textField---if you don't, it's no longer possible to grab the row and drag it around to reorder it. The first click now edits the field instead of dragging.